# How to read yaml collection using Spring Environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I got following yaml file, I have read the file using PropertySource and defined custom YamlPropertySourceFactory referring this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource). I could see values getting populated inside environment variable but I am not able to access them or iterate over them.
For example:

```
environment.getProperty("jms-config.configs[0].cfjndiName"); // returns ab.queue.connection-factory
environment.getProperty("jms-config.configs"); // returns null
```

However, I am looking to read elements under configs as a java object or as a Map/Collection.
Following is my yaml, I know we have annotation @ConfigurationProperties but I want a solution using @PropertySource and without using spring-boot dependencies.

```
jms-config:
     configs:
      - cfJndiName: ab.queue.connection-factory
        destType: Queue
        destJndiName: ab.cd.ef.queue
      - cfJndiName: pq.queue.connection-factory
        destType: Topic
        destJndiName: ab.cd.ef.topic
```

Edit 1:

Following is my class where I have not been using @ConfgiurationProperties from the referenced article as it comes from spring-boot dependency which I don't want to include in my project.

```
@Confgiuration
@ProepertSource(value="classpath:application.yaml")
class PropertiesClass{
  
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;
  
 .....
   environment.getProperty("jms-config.configs[0].cfjndiName"); // returns ab.queue.connection-factory
   environment.getProperty("jms-config.configs"); // returns null
 .....
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `without using spring-boot dependencies`....you have the spring-boot label on your question?

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource  Describes how to load up a YAML into a POJO and inject this POJO..

Answer (score 1):

an option extracting it as `List<Map<String, Object>>`:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

---

```
Iterator<PropertySource<?>> iterator = ((AbstractEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources().iterator();

List<java.util.Map<String, Object>> jmsConfigs = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false)
    .filter(propSource -> (propSource instanceof MapPropertySource))
    .map(propSource -> ((MapPropertySource) propSource).getSource().entrySet()).flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("jms-config.configs"))
    //.map(entry -> Map.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    //.collect(Collectors.toList());
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof String)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().substring(0, entry.getKey().lastIndexOf("."))));

List<Map<String, Object>> jmsConfigsRegrouped = jmsConfigs.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(jmsConfigsRegrouped);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but here in your solution, every key value pair in yaml is converted to a Map; however as per example yaml we should have just 2 jms config maps.

Comment: I updated the answer above to return List of 2 Maps
Hope its closer to what you are looking for